# Show that all elements in each column of these matrices share the same complex argument

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, matrix-equations, quantum-field-theory

As part of my Final Degree Project I am recreating some of the calculations in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2562) by H. Cassini and M. Huerta.

In page 11 we are given the following equations (54-56):

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\alpha^*n\beta^T-\alpha (n+1)\beta^\dagger=\frac{1}{2}\\
\alpha^*n\alpha^T+\alpha (n+1)\alpha^\dagger=X\\
\beta^*n\beta^T+\beta (n+1)\beta^\dagger=P
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are unknown matrices, $n$ is a real diagonal matrix, $X$ and $P$ are both real and symmetric, and $1$ denotes the identity matrix, and $\dagger$ the conjugate transpose (I believe that is all releveant information).

From these equations, it is said in the paper that one can show that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be written as $\alpha=\alpha'U$, and $\beta=\beta'U$, where $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ are both real and $U$ is a diagonal unitary matrix. This essentially amounts to say that all elements in the $i$-th column of both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ share the same complex argument (up to $\pi$, since the elements in $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not necessarily positive). Correct me if I'm wrong. However, I have not managed to prove this, and I have been at it for quite some time.

I know that all three equations can be rewritten as:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\alpha\beta^\dagger=2i\mathrm{Im}(\alpha^*n\beta^T)-\frac{1}{2}\\
\alpha\alpha^\dagger=2\mathrm{Re}(\alpha^*n\alpha^T)+X\\
\beta\beta^\dagger=2\mathrm{Re}(\beta^*n\beta^T)+P
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The last two tell us that $\forall i,j$ we have $\sum_k\alpha_{ik}\alpha_{jk}^*\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sum_k\beta_{ik}\beta_{jk}^*\in\mathbb{R}$, but that doesn't necessarily imply that $\forall i,j,k$ $\alpha_{ik}\alpha_{jk}^*\in\mathbb{R}$ (idem for $\beta$), as the statement requires.

I assume there is something very trivial that I a missing, I just don't know what. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not misquoting the authors, their claim is false. Consider e.g. $n=0$,
$$
\alpha=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1+i}{2}\\ \frac{-1+i}{2}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}},
$$
$\beta=-\frac{1}{2}\alpha$, $X=\alpha\alpha^\dagger$ and $P=\beta\beta^\dagger$. Then $\alpha$ is unitary and all three equations are satisfied, but $\alpha$ cannot possibly be written as the product of a real matrix and a unitary diagonal matrix because $\frac{\alpha_{21}}{\alpha_{11}}$ is not real.

Their claim is true, however, when all singular values of $2n+1$ are distinct. The three equations mean that
$$
\begin{align}
&\alpha\beta^\dagger=-\frac{1}{2}-2i\operatorname{Im}(\alpha n\beta^\dagger),\tag{1}\\
&\alpha\alpha^\dagger\text{ is real},\\
&\beta\beta^\dagger\text{ is real}.\\
\end{align}
$$
Hence $\alpha\alpha^\dagger$ and $\beta\beta^\dagger$ are real positive semidefinite and from the polar decompositions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we see that $\alpha=au$ and $\beta=bv$ for some real positive semidefinite matrices $a,b$ and some unitary matrices $u,v$. Now split equation $(1)$ by real and imaginary parts to obtain
$$
\begin{align}
&\operatorname{Re}(auv^\dagger b^T)=-\frac12,\\
&\operatorname{Im}(au(2n+1)v^\dagger b^T)=0.\tag{2}\\
\end{align}
$$
Note that if $x^Ta=0$ for some real vector $x$, then $0=\operatorname{Re}(x^Tauv^\dagger b^T)=x^T\operatorname{Re}(auv^\dagger b^T)=-\frac12x^T$. Hence $x$ is necessarily zero and $a$ is nonsingular. Likewise, $b$ is nonsingular too. Therefore $(2)$ implies that $r=u(2n+1)v^\dagger$ is a real matrix. So, if all singular values of $2n+1$ are distinct and $q_1\sqrt{(2n+1)^2}\,q_2^T$ is a singular value decomposition of $r$ over $\mathbb R$, we must have $u=q_1w_1$ and $v=q_2w_2$ for some unitary diagonal matrices $w_1$ and $w_2$. Therefore $\alpha=(aq_1)w_1$ is the product of a real matrix $aq_1$ and a unitary diagonal matrix $w_1$ and likewise for $\beta$.